# Hide or Disable the MS Word Pop up menu While Right Click on the Active Document of the Dso Framer Control With Vb 6.0

Tags: vb6, ms-word, dsoframer

I am using the Microsoft DSO Framer Control to view the word document in the Visual Basic Form.

After Hosting(Open) the Word Document in the DSO Framer Control.

While Right Click on the Word Document, Ms word Context Menu is Appearing.

I Want to Hide this Pop up Menu.

Can any One Help me out in this Problem.

I am Waiting for the Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing BeforeRightClick event-handler of Application object.
Here you will get Cancel flag. Check what happens if you set it to true.